# How to unset the session array and empty it so that i can use it again to store the array?

Tags: php

I am really confused with this unset() function of php.

I am implementing the drag and drop feature in the admin site of my project.
i have used jquery ui.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

this is the link for my plugin that i had used for drag and drop feature.

On the right i have all the boxes that are not used on my website.
On the left all the boxes that are currently active(used) on my website.

when i drag a box(on the right) and drop it to left side i pass the box id using Ajax and store it in session so that i can run a query and insert the box into the table when i click on save.

$_session['pID'] is the session variable that is storing the id of the dragged box(from right to left)

i am able to store more than one box id every time i click on save but the problem is that the session contains all the id even after i click on save.

I want the session to destroy the ids after executing the insert query and make the $_session['pID'] empty for next drag and drop operation.

I tried to unset $_session['pID'] but now i am not able to store a single id into the $_session['pID'] array.

Comment: Please show your code to clear understand your case. Your last sentence hard to understand

Comment: can you show a `var_dump()` of your `$_SESSION` Variable when it has a few values in? I'm almost sure it's a multi-level array, and you have to remove only the children nodes

Comment: i got the answer guys i just had to re initialize the array with an empty array like $_SESSION['pID'] = array(); after all the values from it are used for the insert and save operation into the database.